# Https introduces browser back button resubmission issue with Tomcat 10

Tags: tomcat, button, caching, back

Recently I works on a project using tomcat and java. We added https certificate and this introduces browser back button resubmission issue. Instead of going back to the previous page, it says "Confirm Form Resubmission...ERR_CACHE_MISS".
Only difference is https introduced

Answer (score 0):

Playing around, in chrome "inspect" mode, go to "network" tab, then "disable cache", things go smoothly.

After researching:

1. client side, I added into jsp pages the below, to make sure request is not cached.

   > ```
   > <HTML>
   > <HEAD>
   >     <META http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="0">  
   >     <META http-equiv="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">  
   >     <META http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"> 
   > </HEAD> </HTML>
   > ```
2. server side. I followed https://github.com/samaxes/javaee-cache-filter
   (a) add NoCacheFilter class to project containing

   > ```
   > @Override
   > public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
   >         throws IOException, ServletException {
   >     HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;  
   >     httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");   
   >     httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);    
   >     
   >     filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
   > }
   > ```

(b) web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>noCache</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.orgnization.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>noCache</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

3. replaced javascript form.submit() with below

> var formData = new FormData(element.form);  var params = new
> URLSearchParams(formData);   var url = element.form.action + '?' +
> params.toString();  window.location.assign(url);

I tried https://coderanch.com/wiki/659940/Post-Redirect, got the sample working standalone, however when I try to plug into my app, I found out that it is because submit() was used in javascript.